# How to send dynamic value of <div> value through a Form

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I have a  section in which a time is running and not a constant value.
I want to send the latest value inside  through a form.

Please let me know how to send the current running value of the  through form.
Below is my  section,

```
<div id="txt"></div>
```

I have a Javascript function to display value for the

```
//..Inside the java script code...
var output = document.getElementById("txt");
startTime();
//for full code , please visit below link
```

Please look at this page : http://www.chemfluence.org.in/sample.html
[image]

Comment: i dont see anything right now by clicking on ur link

Comment: @MaulikShah : i have attached a image now. pls see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way

```
 <div id="txt"></div>
  <form name='' id='' method='post'>
  <input type='text' name='getmytime' id='getmytime'/>
  <input type='button' name='subtime' id='subtime' value='Submit' onclick='getcurrenttime()'/>
```

And also modify your script like this,

```
function startTime() {
    var now = new Date();
    var display = getVirtual(now);
    output.innerText = format(display);
    document.getElementById("getmytime").value=format(display);//insert the value to textbox
    setTimeout(startTime, 1000/factor - (now.getMilliseconds() % (1000/factor)));
}

function getcurrenttime() {
 alert(document.getElementById("getmytime").value);//get time onclick
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add an `<input type='hidden' name='something' id='something'>` and set its value along with the div:

```
output.innerText = format(display);
outputSubmitter.value = format(display);
```

...

```
var output = document.getElementById("txt");
var outputSubmitter = document.getElementById("something");
```

...

```
<form action="..." method="...">
  <div id="txt"></div>
  <input type='hidden' name='something' id='something' />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add below:

```
document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = format(display);
```